# getting date from timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a PostgreSQL timestamp as

```
2009-12-22 11:01:46
```

I need to change this to date as

```
2009-12-22
```

So that I can compare the dates in `postgreSQL`

How can I achieve this transformation?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Cast it to `date`.

```
SELECT yourtimestamp::date;
```

If you need to extract other kinds of stuff, you might want to use [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) or [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Both links are to the same page, were you'll find more date/time-related functions.

Answer (score 12):

You can either use one of the Postgres [date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html), such as date_trunc, or you could just cast it, like this:

```
SELECT timestamp '2009-12-22 11:01:46'::date

>>> 2009-12-22
```

Comment: date_trunc ('day', yourtimestamp) will return a timesamp, but with hours, mins and secs to zero. It will not convert the value to a date. The cast is the correct anwser.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [timestamp column] ::date;
```

Along in select query you can search on the basis of date

```
WHERE [timestamp column] :: date = '2022-05-30'
```