# Find Earliest Created Record from Each Day

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the earliest `created_at` record by day in a Redshift database:

[image: Database Snapshot]

Ideally this would return the 1st and 3rd record. I am very new to SQL, so I apologize for my idiocy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select date_trunc('day', created_at), min(created_at)
from table
group by date_trunc('day', created_at)
```

Comment: That is the correct answer, but you should try explaining what it is the query does so that Tony can learn from it.

Comment: You have a point. Basically, I am grouping by day. The date_trunc is a function, you can read about this function here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC. By implementing date_trunc('day', created_at) I am grouping by day namely Friday April 1st, Saturday April 2nd etc all unique days. Then I do a min on the actual created_at date to take the min of these. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing something like

SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM day GROUP BY created_at::date

See [getting date from timestamp in PostgresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322969/getting-date-from-timestamp-in-postgressql)