# MySQL get earliest record of each day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

The query below gives me one record per day for each user. How can I modify it so that it gives me the earliest record per day for each user?

I tried using `MIN()` on the `date` field in the `GROUP BY` part, but that obviously doesn't work. There's a `date_trunc` function mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146583/find-earliest-created-record-from-each-day) which seems to do what I want, but it is not available in MySQL. What's the best way to go about this?

For the sample data below, the query should return records with ids 1, 3, 5, and 7.

```
SELECT user_id, coords, date
FROM table
WHERE draft = 0
GROUP BY user_id, DAY('date')

CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coords` point NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `draft` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `user_id`, `coords`, `date`, `draft`) VALUES
(1, 1, xxx, '2020-11-08 18:01:47', 0),
(2, 1, xxx, '2020-11-08 18:05:47', 0),

(3, 1, xxx, '2020-11-09 18:06:47', 0),
(4, 1, xxx, '2020-11-09 18:07:47', 0),

(5, 2, xxx, '2020-11-08 17:01:47', 0),
(6, 2, xxx, '2020-11-08 17:05:47', 0),

(7, 2, xxx, '2020-11-09 14:00:47', 0),
(8, 2, xxx, '2020-11-09 14:05:47', 0),
```

Comment: What is your server version?

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.draft = 0 and t.date = (
    select min(t1.date) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.draft = t.draft and t1.user_id = t.user_id and date(t1.date) = date(t.date)  
)
```

You can optimize the subquery a little by using a half-open interval for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.draft = 0 and t.date = (
    select min(t1.date) 
    from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.user_id = t.user_id 
        and t1.draft = t.draft
        and t1.date >= date(t.date)
        and t1.date <  date(t.date) + interval 1 day
)
```

The second query should be able to take advantage of an index on `(draft, user_id, date)`.

Alternatively, if you are running MuSQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by user_id, date(date) order by date) rn
    from mytable t
    where draft = 0
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT user_id, coords, date
FROM `table`
WHERE draft = 0
GROUP BY DAY('date'), user_id order by user_id, date
```